# Pasting selected tab delimited columns from many files that have the same # of rows in bash

Tags: linux, bash, merge, concatenation, multiple-columns

I found many answers for doing this just for 2 or 3 files, but I have 30 and I couldn't find the answer, so I tried to make a loop that got stuck, and there may be a better way of doing it than using the loop. Made 3 test files to get it to work. All files have the same # of rows and any column can be selected - I chose 3rd one for this example.

#### test1.txt

```
1   A   D  
2   B   E  
3   C   F
```

#### test2.txt

```
1   G   J  
2   H   K  
3   I   L
```

#### test3.txt

```
1   M   P  
2   N   R  
3   O   S
```

#### Desired output, `out.txt`

```
D   J   P  
E   K   R  
F   L   S
```

Made an empty `out.txt` file and looped over the files. The loop got stuck.

```
    $cat out.txt  
    $for file in test*  
    $do  
    $cat > temp.txt  
    $paste temp.txt <(cut -f3 $file) >> out.txt  
    $done
```

Tried to avoid the loop and used test{2..3}.txt with paste - it pasted columns from files 1 and 2 ok, but put the third one in rows 4 - 6.
`$paste test1.txt <(cut -f3 test{2..3}.txt) >> out.txt`

Tried to merge all files, it worked, but not sure how to select just a specific column
`$paste -d'\t' test* >> out.txt`

This one did not work, it made additional rows
`$paste -d'\t' empty_file.txt <(cut -f3 test*) >> out.txt`

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v col=3 '
  BEGIN { FS = OFS = "\t" }
        { out[FNR] = out[FNR] (NR==FNR ? "" : OFS) $col }
    END { for (i = 1; i <= FNR; ++i) print out[i] }
' test*.txt
```

Or, constructing shell commands dynamically:

```
col=3
{ printf 'paste '; printf "<(cut -f $col %q) " test*.txt; echo; } | bash
```

Comment: @Aydin: Sorry, but the 1st one doesn't work for me at all. I'm totally new to bash, so I don't know what I'm missing as I don't understand your code. The second one works, but it's not selecting column 3, it just merges all 3 files together if I direct it to out.txt from bash - same as $paste -d'\t' test* >> out.txt

Comment: One thing I should also clarify is that the code cannot rely on the values 1,2,3... in the 1st column - in my real files, they are the same for each file, but the strings are complicated.

Comment: @EvaColla'kova' are your source *.txt files tab-delimited?  The above solutions worked as expected once I made sure that the source *.txt files were tab-delimited.

Comment: @j_b: Yes, they weren't properly tab delimited. Great point. Output from both codes is the same now, but it was not what I need, though. They both yielded the the 3rd column of the last 2 files only. I made a 4th test file to test it. I have no clue what's wrong.

Comment: The code works for my friend. Not sure what's wrong on my side. Tried it locally on a cluster, still - the same result. Achieved the task by different means. Thank you all for your efforts.

Comment: It works like a charm with my actual files, so something was wrong with my test files. Thanks M. Nejat for your help.